# I get "SyntaxError:Cannot use import statement outside a module", after adding {"type": "module"}

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export, syntax-error

I'm trying to import another .js file in my main server file "App.js", but I keep getting the syntax error:

> SyntaxError:Cannot use import statement outside a module

I did include the "type": "module" in my package.json file.

You can see the line where I'm trying to import the file here;

```
import {Read as readSensor} from './Sensor.js';
```

The function that I'm trying to import looks like this:

```
export async function Read() {
    const res = await fetch(SensorUrl);
    if(res.ok){
        return await res.json();
    }
    else{
        throw new Error('Bad Reading');
    }
}
```

AFAIK, the syntax of my import/exports is correct, so I really cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you try something like `import {Read as readSensor} from './Sensor.mjs';` ?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I tried to rename App.js to App.mjs, and then I get 
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: (path)\app.mjs

Answer (score 2):

If you are using node js v14 or above, try these:

add `"type": "module"` in your package.json
use `--experimental-modules` when launching your app, eg: `node --experimental-modules index.js`

Or you can try this also:

add `"type": "module"` in your package.json and rename your file with a .mjs extension, the file will look like something `Sensor.mjs`.

Feel free to add a comment if you face any issue, also pls add your `package.json` file with `node version` for better debugging.

Have a look at this [link](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/12/04/whats-new-nodejs-2020), it might help you.

Answer (score -1):

So, I figured it out, and it turns out I'm dumb. I was trying to run this with an outdated version of node.js (12.14.1).
It worked as soon as I updated to version 16.14.2.
So today I have learned the very valuable lesson of keeping my stuff updated.
Thank you for the answers!

Comment: yeah, thats why i asked you to check node version.